# Spring MVC - Separation of logic RestController and Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I started using Spring MVC to build my first REST API :) Now I struggle a bit of where to put which logic. I read the following:
`@RestController`: Handles requests, defines the API the user can use
`@Service`: Contains the business logic
`@Repository`: Abstracts away from access to DB

In an easy first example, I saw the flow was like this: RestController calls Service, Service calls Repository. In the first step, I did it like this.

Now I want to use `ResponseEntity` - I hear it is good practice to use that. But now I start wondering: Should the service layer return `ResponseEntity` or just the instances of the domain model?

To show what I mean (yes, I am a big football fan):

```
@GetMapping("/clubs")
public ResponseEntity<List<FootballClub>> getAllClubs(@RequestParam String footballLeague) {
    List<FootballClub> clubs = service.getAllClubs(footballLeague);
    return new ResponseEntity(...);
}
```

Is it best practice to do it like this or to let the Service return the `ResponseEntity`? I am new to Spring MVC. I read some articles on Stackoverflow and some explain the general setup. But I could not find how to deal with for instance `ResponseEntity`.

I think you can argue that `ResponseEntity` should also be in Service as you might need to return method not allowed or something like this and determining whether to return a method not allowed `ResponseEntity` or an OK Entity could be considered part of the business logic. But I don't know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Short Answer**

Yes, `Service` returning domain object should be preferable to a `Service` returning `ResponseEntity<>`.

> **Long Answer**

There is no [best practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164). Having said that, you should think of implementing something like Hexagonal or Layered architecture. In Hexagonal architecture, application/domain logic is confined in application/domain layer which is separated from presentation, persistence/infrastructure layer. Interfaces are defined in application layers (called ports) and implementation is provided in infrastructure layer (called adapters). There is an [excelled article on this](https://herbertograca.com/2017/11/16/explicit-architecture-01-ddd-hexagonal-onion-clean-cqrs-how-i-put-it-all-together/).

Concepts like `Service`, `Repository` is taken from `DDD`. To know more about DDD you can check Vaughn Vernon book [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577).

Answer (score 1):

The service should returns instances of the domain model. The ResponseEntity (which is related to the Response the controller returns after request elaboration) should be created at controller level.